# cocoa + skip os generated files

Tags: cocoa

my app actually goes to different folders and takes each file into account and reads each file and does a lot of processing on them and marks the folder it has processed as done. but this is not happening as the system is immediately generating files like .DS_store and .localized and .trash. so is there any mechanism to skip processing hidden files or stop the os from generating these files programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you change your app to just ignore files that start with "."? You've tagged this Cocoa, so using something like NSFileManager's **contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:** seems appropriate. One of the options you can specify is NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles, which will skip hidden files.
Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But if i skip files which i start with '.' then all hidden files will be skipped even the files which are not generated by os. is there any method to identify if a file is os generated or not?

Comment: I guess that would depend on what you mean by "os generated". A lot of dot-files are generated by different parts of the OS. The Finder makes some, Spotlight search makes some others, Time Machine makes some, etc , etc, so there won't be a comprehensive list anywhere. 

A lot of third-party software makes hidden files, too. I think that you're going to have to make a list of "files to ignore" in your app. Make sure it's user-editable, too - some editors use dot-files for backups, and then there are .svn directories...

Comment: And for what it's worth, most of the command-line tools ignore hidden files unless they're specifically told to process them. Are you sure there are going to be hidden files that you want to process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any option that disables the generation of .DS_Store files locally. There is an option for remote, [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629).

Another way to do it could be to create a unix user for just that job and let him own the dirs, so that the Finder never can go there. Either start the job manually using sudo, or make it a setuid job.. or use launchd.

Comment: Thanks neoneye for the reply. is there any way to identify if a file is os generated hidden file?

or can you list files which are os generated for folders. i know three of them 
1. .DS_Store
2. .localized
3. .trash
Are there any other hidden files which are OS generated files for MAC.

Thanks

Comment: There is also a .CFUserTextEncoding in the homedir. If you look in the root dir of a volume there are some more hidden files: 1. .fseventsd 2. .HFS+ Private Directory Data 3. .Spotlight-V100 4. TemporaryItems 5. \\\\HFS+ Private Data 6. .com.apple.timemachine.supported 7. .journal 8. .journal_info_block.  Maybe you can have a text file for your program with filenames to ignore, so that you still can process dotfiles and ignore the apple system files.

Comment: Also the hidden flag is only set on some of the files.